# How to fix svn issue - Error running context: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host?

Tags: windows-10, tortoisesvn

I have been getting this issue when i perform svn update for a shared directory(on remte server) from my local windows machine.
"Error running context: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."
The directory is very large with several folders and sub-folders. How should i fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you're sharing a Subversion working copy with other coworkers using a Windows share, that outcome is to be expected because the system is not designed with that scenario in mind. Subversion needs exclusive access to the `.svn` directory and a reasonably fast disk access that most LAN setups don't offer.

There's even an [entry in the FAQ section](https://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#wconshare) of TortoiseSVN documentation:

> **Can I store a working copy on a network share?**
>
> This depends on the network share. But we really, really urge you to
>   not do this! Even if you're using a Windows server and use those
>   network shares, the fcntl() file locking is not fully reliable. And
>   for Samba based shares all bets are off. Which means you will get a
>   corrupted working copy and you then will lose data! Maybe not today,
>   maybe not tomorrow, but someday you will.

Whatever your use case is, your current toolchain cannot cope with it.